# text of checkbox in django forms

Tags: html, css, django

I have a form which goes like this:

```
class ContributorSearchForm(forms.Form):
      colour = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class':'browse-label-text'}), required=False, choices = ([ ('Brown','Brown'),('Gray','Gray'),('Yellow','Yellow'),
        ('Purple','Purple')]))

      material_type = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class':'browse-label-text'}), required=False, choices = ([ ('Wood','Wood'),\
        ('Steel/Iron/Metal','Steel/Iron/Metal')]))
```

Now when i render my form in html with this code:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'ideaview' %}">
{% for field in form %}
<div class="browse-menu-ul">
{{field}}<a href="#">{{field.label_tag}}</a>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Output is:

```
<li><label for="id_colour_0"><input class="browse-label-text" id="id_colour_0" name="colour" type="checkbox" value="Brown"> Brown</label></li>
```

I want to add class or add some css to Color name "Brown" in above li.
How can we do so ?

Answer (score 0):

One way to add class is by using `jQuery`

```
  $("id_colour_0").addClass("myClass");
```

Comment: I want to add class to all of my choices, so this wont work :(

Comment: Do you want to add same class or different class to each element?

Comment: Try this `$('div.browse-menu-ul li').addClass('myClass');`

Comment: above will add class to li

Comment: Oops. You can try `$('div.browse-menu-ul li > label > input').addClass('myClass');`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61680/discussion-between-chillaranand-and-vijay-shanker).